# WPF Terminal/CMD Control - How to do it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, powershell

I'm looking for a way to host a WPF-native Windows terminal or PowerShell inside WPF - natively in WPF.  Ideally this would not involve an HwndHost-style approach with SetParent, but would actually be a fully-native WPF control that can display true Terminal output.

I have found a few things out there, but nothing is complete enough in its implementation to successfully support a simple test case:

- SSH into a remote computer
- Run a complex console app like VIM and have it render correctly

So I was wondering if anyone out there had a solution for showing a true terminal/CMD window natively in WPF?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: I want to have a 100% pure WPF app and not mix airspaces between Win32 and WPF